# aria role=alert used for each validation error

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have code that generates an inline validation error for each form field that is invalid, e.g.

```
<div>
  <label for="ctrl2">Country of birth</label>
  <input type="text"id="ctrl2" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="ctrl2-error" aria-labelledby="ctrl2-error" name="countryOfBirth"><option value=""/>
</div>
<div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div id="ctrl2-error" class="form-group" role="alert" aria-hidden="false">
    <ul>
      <li>Country of birth is required.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The screen reader only reads the first validation error if I have more than one element.

Is there a way to make the screen reader read each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertive type of aria-live will not only interrupt the user's current announcement, it will stop the screenreader's current batch of announcements. So it can't be used the way you are planning.

You could use aria-live=polite but this will also be quite intrusive and isn't really necessary. A better error message design pattern for all users would be to have an error summary where you say something like "there are 3 fields which need to be fixed before you can submit this form". You can send focus to it on submit, and let the user control how they deal with this information.

To make a screenreader announce an error when the user reaches the field to correct it (rather than when you detect the mistake), you can add an aria-describedby="ctrl2-error" at the same time you append the error div.

There's some examples in this post on Medium: [Create simple, accessible web forms](https://medium.com/net-magazine/create-simple-accessible-web-forms-535cd253dee2).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, when an element with aria-live=assertive appears or is modified, it makes the screen reader immediately read it, interrupting anything that is currently being read elsewhere.
IN the opposite, aria-live=polite tells the screen reader to read the content without interrupting anything.

This implicitely implies that, if there are multiple aria-live=assertive appearing/being modified simultaneously or too quickly, only a single one will be read entirely (an aria-live=assertive interrupts another one too).
The others will be instantly interrupted and you have no way of knowing which one will finally be read; it's not always necessarily the first or the last one.

Knowing this, if we assume that the theory is always correct, I would suggest trying to replace assertive by polite.

However, the reality is much more complicated than that: some screen readers and/or browsers are known to absolutely not follow this theory.
You will have to make compromises between the problem you are raising here and the fact that some screen readers and/or browsers won't read everything or even anything at all if you aren't using the right combination of role+aria-live+aria-relevant+aria-atomic attributes.
The best way to find the most satisfying solution is to test yourself...

Practically speaking, I think that your problem is probably one of the less worse solution (in this context, it's certainly better to have something spoken, even if not everything, rather than nothing at all). Perhaps leaving as it is finally isn't that bad, as long as the user can manually reach and read all error messages as he goes through the different fields.

P.S. Remove aria-hidden=false. It is probably useless and I have already observed that sometimes it behaves as if aria-hidden=true